# Intellij,is there a way to auto add dependencies to pom?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml, dependency-management

Most likely a dumb question, but I've recently started working with maven and the Intellij IDE (super usefull, wish i new of this ide earlier).

Currently attempting to make an Spring API application from scratch, but Im currently have to manually add all dependencies to my Pom, this is starting to get quite annoying and I feel intelij should be smart enough to provide this quality of life.

Is there some sort of setting for intellij to add new dependencies to the pom without me having to manually do so in the pom? I know of the auto import maven setting for the project, but when I need to add new libraries to the project, I end up needing to dig into the maven website for the dependency code.

Example: was adding lombok annotations to my models, yet the IDE was not able to find the lombok library, so I had to browse the new for the lombok dependency to add to my pom; so maven can download it. I feel there should be an automatic way for this. Or am i just wishing for luxury?

Comment: IDE couldn't search through maven repository for a library that contains missing class, but you could open pom.xml, run "Code | Generate... | Dependency..." and use opened dialog to find dependency

Comment: @y.bedrov You actually answered the question!  Saved a lot of time, awesome!